# renderPrint option in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm using the `renderPrint` function in a ShinyApp to show calculation results. The results come with a `[1],[2]` etc in front.

Is there a way to get rid of that?

Also, can one change fonts of the output?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `renderText` instead of `renderPrint`. Or maybe [`withMathJax()`](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/019-mathjax) could also be an option?

For styling your app, there are several ways to do that. You can read about that [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). I include the css directly in the app in the following example. For small adaptations thats maybe the easiest way, for more complex apps, I would use a css file and include it with `includeCSS("www/style.css")` or `tags$head(tags$style("www/style.css"))`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    #renderprint {
                      color: white;
                      background: blue;
                      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
                      font-size: 20px;
                      font-style: italic;
                    }
                    #rendertext {
                      color: blue;
                      background: orange;
                      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
                      font-size: 12px;
                      font-weight: bold;
                    }
                    #rendertext1 {
                      color: red;
                      background: yellow;
                      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                      font-size: 19px;
                    }
                    "))
    ),

  verbatimTextOutput("renderprint"),

  verbatimTextOutput("rendertext"),
  textOutput("rendertext1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$renderprint <- renderPrint({
    print("This is a render Print output")
  })  
  output$rendertext <- renderText({
    "This is a render Text output - with verbatimTextOutput"
  })
  output$rendertext1 <- renderText({
    "This is a render Text output - with textOutput"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful!

Comment: I edited my answer and included some examples for css-styling.